# How can i make this work. I am basically making my own wordle game but i ran into an issue

Tags: python

```
import random
import linecache

import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

def pickword():
  global wrd
  fp = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
  x = random.randint(0,0)
  wrd = fp.readlines()[x]
  
def split(word):
    return list(word.lower())
  
def checkword():
  var1 = 0
  ans = input("\n\nEnter a Word: ")
  lst = split(wrd)
  wrdlst = []
  for x in lst:
    if x != "\n":
      wrdlst.append(x)
  anslst = split(ans)
  k = anslst[var1]
  l = wrdlst[var1]
  for i in range(len(wrdlst)):
    print(Style.RESET_ALL + l)
    for m in range(1):
      k = anslst[var1]
      l = wrdlst[var1]
      if k not in wrdlst:
        print(Fore.RED + k)
      elif k in wrdlst and k != l:
        print(Fore.YELLOW + k)
      elif k in wrdlst and k == l:
        print(Fore.GREEN + k)
      var1 = var1 + 1
      print(var1)
  
# def playerInputCheck(anslist, wrdlist):
  #x=1
  #for i in wrdlst:
   # for m in anslst:  
    #  if m == i:
     #   print("3")

def main():
  start = input(Fore.GREEN + "Hello, welcome to wordle! To get started press enter:\n\n*Hit enter to start* ")
  pickword()
  checkword()

  
main()
```

When I try to run this, it ends up outputting this:

```
Hello, welcome to wordle! To get started press enter:

*Hit enter to start* 


Enter a Word: about
a
a
1
a
b
2
b
o
3
u
u
4
s
t
5
```

the word i am getting from the file is abuse, but for some reason it is outputting the first a twice and not getting to the e (the top letters are from abuse and the bottom ones are from about) I tried to make a work around but i just couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down at the problem area (irrelevant parts removed):

```
l = wrdlst[var1]
for i in range(len(wrdlst)):
    print(Style.RESET_ALL + l)
    
        k = anslst[var1]
        l = wrdlst[var1]
        
        var1 = var1 + 1
        print(var1)
```

The first time through, we have `var1 = 0`, `l = wrdlst[var1] = 0th letter` to start. Print out `l`.

We enter the loop, `k = wrdlst[var1] = 0th letter`, `l = wrdlst[var1] = 0th letter`. `var1` goes up by 1. `k` gets printed.

Going into the loop the second time, we print out `l` (the 0th letter, again). `k = wrdlst[var1] = 1st letter`, `l = wrdlst[var1] = 1st letter`. `var1` goes up by 1. `k` gets printed.

As you see, `l` gets set once outside the loop, and then printed inside the loop, and then gets accidentally reset back to the beginning inside the loop, so it's always one behind.

Simplest solution, move `l = wrdlst[var1]` to inside the loop, like so:

```
    for i in range(len(wrdlst)):
        l = wrdlst[var1]
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + l)
        for m in range(1):
            k = anslst[var1]
            if k not in wrdlst:
                print(Fore.RED + k)
            elif k in wrdlst and k != l:
                print(Fore.YELLOW + k)
            elif k in wrdlst and k == l:
                print(Fore.GREEN + k)
            var1 = var1 + 1
            print(var1)
```

[output of suggested code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4mbp.png)